# Embed node.js application from java project with J2V8 - resolving relative paths in node.js

Tags: java, node.js, j2v8

Having problem while running Node.js application (1) on the JVM using J2V8 from another Java-based application (2). Starting script of application (1) fails on line

```
fs.readFileSync('./lib/someFile.json')
```

because J2V8 provides `'.'` path to an application (2) root directory 
but I need `'.'` to be path to an application (1) root directory.

How can I deal with it only making changes in project (2)?

UPDATE: added Java code which starts node.js application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final NodeJS nodeJS = NodeJS.createNodeJS();
        File nodeScript = new File("/media/Projects/Test/start.js");
        nodeJS.exec(nodeScript);
        while(nodeJS.isRunning()) {
            nodeJS.handleMessage();
        }
        nodeJS.release();
}
```

Comment: Your English is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) to have the path to the directory where your Node script is in.

For example:

```
fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/lib/someFile.json');
```

might do what you need.

Or using [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path):

```
var path = require('path');
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'lib', 'someFile.json');
```

with `path.join` you can do things like:

```
console.log(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'lib', 'someFile.json'));
```

to access `lib` that is one level up from your Node program etc. Also, thanks to `path.join` you don't have to think about path delimiters on different operating systems (like `/` on Unix/Linux and `\` on Windows).

Making only changes to your Java project you would have to run your Node application with a different working directory. It depends how you run it but what you should do is change directory to the one that you want to have the `'.'` point to before running the Node application. You have provided no code example of actually running the Node application from your Java application so it's hard to say anything more.

### Update

It seems that you're using J2V8. There is an open issue on GitHub related to what you're trying to do:
[Issue #185: Set the working directory](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/issues/185).

You may try to change the working directory before you start your Node program from Java - using whatever is the Java equivalent of the [`chdir`](http://www.manpages.info/linux/chdir.2.html) system call.

Alternatively you can copy your Node program into your Java project, so that their `'.'` directories are the same, so that you could call it with:

```
File nodeScript = new File("./start.js");
```

When you can call `start.js` as `./start.js` then the `'.'` in Node should be the directory where the `start.js` file is located in.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, it`s perfect for node.js side. Added Java code which starts node.js application, please let me now if you'll have some ideas how to solve this issue from Java side.

Comment: @DmitryAleshkevich so it seems that you're using J2V8 - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it really helps.